# how layers work in kivy, understand index in widgets

Tags: kivy

how index work in kivy Widgets?

I want to output 3 widgets (with colors: red, green, blue), and put the red in front of all, once his index is the highest,

but instead kivy is drawing 3 widgets, one of them is white (instead of green), and the red is in the middle of them (instead of in front)

.kv:

```
<Red>:
    x: 0
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
        Color:
            rgba: 1,0,0,1

<Green>:
    x: 40
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
        Color:
            rgba: 0,1,0,1

<Blue>:
    x: 80
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0,0,1,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window


class Red(Widget):
    pass


class Green(Widget):
    pass


class Blue(Widget):
    pass


class MainWidget(Widget):
    pass
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


        self.add_widget(Red(), index=3)
        self.add_widget(Green())
        self.add_widget(Blue())


class Test2App(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.size = (300, 300)
        self.main_widget = MainWidget()
        return self.main_widget

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Test2App().run()
```

### [image]

my questions are:

- why one of the widgets are white and not green?
- why the Red Widget is not in front of all (highest index)

Comment: One issue is that you are using the `Color` in `kv` after the `Rectangle`. The `Color` sets the color for the graphics object that appear after it. So `Red` ends up the default color (white), and `Green` ends up red, because `Red` changed the color after drawing its `Rectangle`. And `Blue` does it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Question 1

> why one of the widgets are white and not green?

### Answer

The first widget is white because in your kv file, it specified to draw the rectangle first without specifying the colour before hand. Therefore, it used the default colour which is white.

## Question 2

> why the Red Widget is not in front of all (highest index)

### Answer

Actually the red widget is in front of all the other widgets. It is just the colour that is out of sequence.

## Solution

Place the `Color` attribute before drawing the rectangle and the rest of the code just works fine.

## Snippets - kv file

```
<Red>:
    x: 0
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1,0,0,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<Green>:
    x: 40
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0,1,0,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<Blue>:
    x: 80
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0,0,1,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

## Output

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

One issue is that you are using the `Color` in kv after the `Rectangle`. The `Color` sets the color for the graphics object that appear after it. So `Red` ends up the default color (white), and `Green` ends up red, because `Red` changed the color after drawing its Rectangle. And `Blue` does it correctly.

The `index` argument of `add_widget` indicates where in the list of children the added `Widget` should be placed. The default is to insert the added `Widget` at an index of zero, and the widgets are drawn from high index to low, so the last added gets drawn on top. Note that using `index=3` on the first `add_widget()` will have no effect, because `index` is an index into the list of children and, at that point, the list of children is empty. You can see this effect using:

```
    self.add_widget(Red())
    self.add_widget(Green())
    self.add_widget(Blue(), index=2)
```

The above code ends up with the list of children in the order `Green`, `Red`, then `Blue` (in order of index). They are drawn in reverse order, so `Green` will end up in front. Of course, you need to correct your use of `Color` first.